# How to display the node variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
 credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

let fs = admin.firestore();
let auth = admin.auth();

    async function start (object){
  const info = await fs.collection('users').doc(object.uid).get();
  if (!liam.exists) {
    console.log('No document');
   } else {
    console.table([info.data()]);
   }
}
```

I want to send `console.table([info.data()]);` data to the webpage table, I can't send it to HTML with `<script>` tag and send data with `document.getElement`.

All I wanted is just send to viw in webpage insted of console, how can I do that?

Comment: You'll need to write a front end in something like React/Vue/Svelte for that

Comment: @Mikkel you can do it with plain Javascript

Comment: @ManuelMB How to do it, can you please give me an example?

Comment: if you dont care about anything else in the document this will work
`document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(info.data(), null, 2)`
depending on what info.data retunrs

Comment: @eltonkamami the use of firebase-admin it's because he/she is working on the server side, not the front end, so he/she will need something like express to show the result in the front end.

Comment: @eltonkamami It is giving error: **ReferenceError: document is not defined**

Comment: Take a look to this tutorial from Firebase. https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firestore-web#0